# Java XML DocumentBuilderFactory write empty tags <Tag /> from null values

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Hey so I'm wondering how it is possible to write a empty tag for example `<Category />` with the `DocumentBuilderFactory`  (based off this [resource](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/), library *`javax.xml.parsers.*;`*), as for the moment I'm having to apply an if condition `if object.getCategory() != null` then create the `Category Tag` otherwise ignore it.

```
//add the Category
if(excel.getCategory() != null){
    Element Category = doc.createElement("category");
    Category.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(excel.getCategory()));
    Rows.appendChild(Category);
}
```

And Schema

```
<xs:complexType name="data">
    <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="Category" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    <!-- other columns.. -->
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

And I've noticed if I add a textnode that is null, the `transformer.transform(source, result);` will return with a heap of `NullException` errors. Is there a way to configure the transformer to know that the TextNode is intentionally left empty? and in turn create `<Category />` or `<Category></Category>`.

Comment: Is this a valid schema?  `use="required"` applies to attributes, you use `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` for elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//add the Category
Element Category = doc.createElement("category");
Rows.appendChild(Category);
if(excel.getCategory() != null){
    Category.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(excel.getCategory()));
}
```

Here I'm adding the `category` element to `Rows` unconditionally, but only adding a text node child if `getCategory()` is non-null.  If it is null, then this will create an empty `category` element, which will serialize to XML as `<category />`.

If you want to be able to distinguish in the XML between a `null` value for `excel.getCategory()` and an empty string value, then the usual XML schema idiom for that is to make the element "nillable"

```
<xs:complexType name="data">
    <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="Category" type="xs:string" nillable="true" />
    <!-- other columns.. -->
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

and mark it with `xsi:nil`

```
//add the Category
Element Category = doc.createElement("category");
Rows.appendChild(Category);
if(excel.getCategory() != null){
    Category.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(excel.getCategory()));
} else {
    Category.setAttributeNS(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI,
                            "xsi:nil", "true");
}
```

This will produce

```
<category />
```

when `excel.getCategory().equals("")` and

```
<category xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
```

when `excel.getCategory() == null`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! its cool to know the compiler doesn't mind in which order things are added.